# The results within the page results do not lead to the nodes

Tags: nodes, views

I do not know how to treat *this problem* with Drupal. I hope you can help me.

Suppose this. We have a glossary (Views), which shows the items of the content type called "Glossary".

I created a search engine Views, following [these instructions](http://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/how-create-search-pages-using-views-drupal-7).

Now, I open my website and try to find one of the words of my glossary site.

Result: Well, the results page returns the title of one of the nodes of content type "Glossary", good! If I click on that word, then word node (which belongs to the glossary) is displayed.

But I do not want the node is displayed. I want that word is displayed within the glossary. Glossary nodes should not be viewed independently.

Is it possible that the word shown in the results page glossary is leading the glossary, and not their respective node?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change the link settings from within the field settings on the view (or, if you are rendering nodes, you will have to change it in the display settings or template files if you are showing teasers using default templates).

Once you've edited your view, you might consider using the [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module to further deal with unwanted Node views.

Comment: Oh! That sounds good! I'll try the module and return to report the results.